# Read sht31 sensors by I2C

Tags: i2c

I have a SHT31 sensors (temp/humidity) from Adafruit : https://www.adafruit.com/products/2857

With my raspberry I can detect this sensor :

dmesg | grep i2c

```
[    4.338498] i2c /dev entries driver
[    7.843299] bcm2708_i2c 20804000.i2c: BSC1 Controller at 0x20804000(irq 79) (baudrate 100000)
[ 4079.357467] i2c i2c-1: new_device: Extra parameters
[ 4091.539938] i2c i2c-1: new_device: Extra parameters
```

and it's detected at 0x44 address :
i2cdetect -y 1

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- 44 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

There are some C code from Adafruit : https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_SHT31

and datasheet from Sensirion

But at this time I can only get a : 0x00 or 0 value :-(

Do you know if I can use Wiring Pi and I2C Library ? and how ?

Thanks

Comment: did you ever get this resolved? Can you tell us how?

Comment: Yes with a python script : https://github.com/jaques/sht21_python